# Does Craft support international urls?

Tags: localization, url

If I create an entry with international characters in urls? e.g. for Polish language?

If I create an entry with the word "ułatwienia" in the url, it doesn't work (I get Craft serving up the 404 page), I take out the special ł character and it's fine.

Although interestingly, the Live Preview url works fine with the special character included.

Have I missed something?

Answer (score 1):

That should work fine and I just tested locally with a fresh Craft installation on the latest build and `ułatwienia` works in the slug for me.

Maybe you've got the [limitAutoSlugsToAscii](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#limitAutoSlugsToAscii) config setting set to true and `ł` gets changed to `l` in the slug, but you're still entering `ł` in the URL?

Comment: Checked if this was option was set but it wasn't and explicity setting it to false didn't change anthing.I wondered if this was relating to my hosting on Windows/IIS since I was seeing the `ł` character being replaced with `?` in the craft logs for the request. I've just moved my setup to a LAMP server, no other changes, and its working fine. Thanks

Comment: Possible, I suppose. I've got a Windows/IIS box I'll test on to make sure.